# Save/restore form data after locale change

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a database app written in PHP (jQuery/JS on the front end) that has bilingual labels/text.  Currently one can only change one's language on a maintenance page (form submission, then PHP updates a session variable with their new language choice), but the users would like me to add a language pulldown that would appear in the corner of all pages.  When the page contains a form, I don't want users to lose their partially entered data if they happen to change the language, so I need to save/restore the form data somehow.  Is there an easy way to do that?  I know I can use jQuery to serialize the form, but then what?  Send that added onto the URL and pick it up in PHP?  Then what?  Write some routine to loop through the form fields and handle them properly (inputs, selects, radio boxes, etc. are all different)?  It seems like there should be an easier way.  I don't mind restricting myself to HTML5-supported solutions or adding jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 1):

How about [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage)?

If user has filled any input fields, save them to localStorage and delete the data after user submits the form.

Comment: Or sessionStorage - yeah, those two are why I mentioned HTML5 in my question.  But I thought this need would be common enough that there would be some pre-written functions or something, rather than me having to write and debug the code to collect and store all the fields' values to the storage and then populate/select/check each of the form fields from the storage.  Yeah, I'm lazy, but does someone know of a shortcut?  I keep googling, but I haven't run across anything yet.  As I said, jQuery can serialize the form in one function call, but restoration is more cumbersome.

Comment: I haven't stumbled on anything similar either. jQuery makes these kind of things quite easy so I wouldn't expect this kind of plugin take more than 2 lazy hours.

Good luck!

Comment: I hear you.  I'm not a jQuery pro yet, so it might take me a little longer than that, but yeah, it's doable.  I just didn't want to reinvent the wheel if something already existed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to:

Submit the Language and any wanted user data when changing language to the server using `$.ajax` or `$.post`

Comment: AJAX is not relevent here, because I need to refresh the whole page in order for PHP to put the right language text in all the spots of the markup.  (It would be far more work to use jQuery to replace all the little bits of text all over the page than to save the form data.)